# Can object’s property be used, if object used in another thread?

Tags: c++, stdthread

Can the example below make undefined behavior and crash when main thread try to call `SetX`, because, although `x` property is not being accessed in new thread, but `object` itself is?

```
class Object{
public:
int x;
int y;

Object(int x, int y)
{
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
}

void SetX(int x)
{
this->x = x;
}

}*object = nullptr;

int *value_only = nullptr;

void ch()
{
    while(true) // assume there is some mechanism to quit loop
    {
         //with obj variable
         //readonly
         auto link = obj;
         auto y = obj->y;

         //write
         obj->y = 5;


         //without obj variable
         //read
         auto yy = *value_only;

         //write
         *value_only = 2;


         // note that obj->x is not touched
    }
}

int main()
{
obj = new Object(1,2);
value_only = &obj->y;

thread th(ch);

obj->SetX(4);

// assume, th termination is handled

return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, x and y are entirely separate objects so there's no race condition

Comment: the program exits abnormally by calling `std::terminate` which will call `std::exit` because you do not join the thread. I think we had the discussion already: You need to join the thread before you return from `main`

Comment: Yes it can be use, but 1) the object lifetime must be guaranteed to exceed or match the lifetime of a thread (can be achieved by passing a shared_ptr to object to thread). 2) the member data must be protected (e.g. be a mutex) if it can be accessed by multiple threads. Have a look at : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda. In this case `obj_ptr = std::make_shared<Object>(1,2); auto future = std::async(std::launch::async([obj_ptr]{obj_ptr->setX(4);`

Comment: @AlanBirtles even despite the fact that to use `x` and `y` I need to use `object`?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I understand, it is just for simple example

Comment: @PepijnKramer should member data be protected in the exactly  example code?

Comment: provoking a crash and leaking memory is not making it "simpler"

Comment: It is a good habit, not all variables will update in one CPU instruction on all platforms.

Comment: You forgot to add th.join(); in main(). That was making the crash.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number and mmj, added some comments

Comment: comments don't make code more correct. Rather than comments you could have added `th.join()` and removed the dynamic allocation of `object`, they are not essential for the question, but present issues in the code that distract from the actual question. Anyhow, I addressed both in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no issue with accessing two different members of the same object.

Note that both members are public and the setter doesn't do anything but set the member. Hence, you could rewrite `ch` to take a reference to `obj->y` as parameter and also in main, rather than calling `SetX` it could use `int& x = obj->x;`. Maybe then it is more obvious that the two threads do not actually share data.

In the thread you copy `obj` but that merely copies the pointer.

However, your program will crash due to not joining the thread. `std::thread` calls `std::terminate` when not joined (or detached) in its destructor. In any case you leak the memory of `obj`. While leaking memory on return from `main` is not a big deal, `obj` may manage other resources (files, db connections, etc) that need to be properly closed in the destructor.

Comment: This reads like *"I cannot imagine why this operation could be problematic, thus the behavior must be well defined"*. This is not how you'd argue for a piece of code being correct. Instead, you'd provide a reference to the rule(s) that explain why this is correct code. If it is, there MUST be at least one rule in the language specification that covers this.

Answer (score 0):

My comments in code :

```
#include <future>
#include <mutex>

class Object
{
public:
    Object(int x, int y) :
        m_x{ x },
        m_y{ y }
    {
    }

    void SetX(int x)
    {
        m_x = x;
    }

    int GetX()
    {
        return m_x;
    }

private:
    int m_x;        
    int m_y;
};

int main()
{
    auto obj_ptr = std::make_shared<Object>(1, 2);

    // capture obj_ptr by value, making a copy of shared_ptr will increase its 
    // reference count. When the lambda finishes the shared_ptr will decrease the reference count.
    auto future = std::async([obj_ptr]
        {
            obj_ptr->SetX(3);
        });

    // destructor of the future will block until async is complete
    // so no race condition at shutdown
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no mutex is required. In Ops code one thread reads and writes `y` and two threads only read `x`

Comment: True, but it is a good pattern to learn.

Comment: As your code is only accessing the object from a single thread the mutex seems unnecessary? The original code also had no race condition necessitating a mutex?

Comment: yes, but the question is "is it a problem to use `obiect` in two threads?"

Comment: Sorry, but You didn’t catch the main idea of the example I provided — same object members are not used in different thread. One thread uses only `y` in many variations, one only `x`. Do I need mutex in this case, because, although members are not shared, but to get/set members I need to get members object?

Comment: The answer then is yes if you manage the lifetime of the object and thread correctly. And no you will not need the mutex then.

Comment: I can accept Your answer, if You, please, edit it respectively the question

Comment: Example updated, this example would also work without the shared_ptr by the way. Since a locally defined Object will live longer then the future created later.

Comment: actually I misread the code. A mutex is needed to protect `SetX` in the main thread to interfer with `auto link = obj;` in the other thread. `link` is unused, nevertheless its an issue

Comment: There is no set in the mainthread (m_x is initialized in constructor, but no threads will access it then), SetX is only used from the thread used by std::async. Either way it is always a good idea to do threading/locking by design up front.